# CSS Transform. Will the performance be increased if i define size and position in pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

There are many objects (more than 80), **their position and size is defined in percentage**. Position of elements changes with translate3d by specific formula every time you scroll. **Will the performance be increased if i define size and position in pixels?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the sizes are set (meaning the animation is *not* responsive - manual recalculations don't need to occur when switching to pixels), switching from percentages to pixels will improve performance ***very slightly*** better than before because ultimately they have to be rendered in pixels.

However, the difference, in practice, can be ignored, but it does occur.